# Powerpoint VBA Automation Slow when running in excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am using an excel macro to build a table on a power point slide, and it is incredibly slow iterating through cell (about 1-2 second for each cell). Is there a way to make this process go faster? Here is my Code:

```
Private Function formatTable(shp As PowerPoint.Shape)

Dim i As Byte
Dim j As Byte
Dim k As Byte
Dim tabCol As Byte
With shp.Table
    tabCol = .Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To tabCol
            With .Cell(i, j).Shape
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
                    Select Case i
                        Case 1 ' Header Row
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                        Case 2, 6, 10, 14, 19 'Elements
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
                        Case 23 'Satisfaction
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 153)
                        Case 27, 29, 31   'Future Behaviors
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(204, 255, 104)
                        Case Else
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse
                    End Select
                    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                        .Name = "Arial"
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(i = 1, vbWhite, vbBlack)
                        .Size = IIf(j <> 1 And i = 1, 7, 8)
                    End With
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = IIf(j = 1, ppAlignLeft, ppAlignCenter)
            End With
            With .Cell(i, j)
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Weight = 1
                .Borders(ppBorderTop).Weight = 1
                .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Weight = 1
                .Borders(ppBorderRight).Weight = 1
            End With
        Next
    Next
End With

End Function
```

Comment: + 1 Good question :) Almost had me thinking for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that is the only way that I know of coloring the cells in a table. I.e. via looping. However you can reduce the time drastically :)

Did you notice the `Case Else` part? That is the majority of the table. So you can actually remove that from the code and color the entire table in one go using the below code

`oPPSlide.Shapes(1).Table.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)`

and you can remove the `Case Else` part. So you will have to loop less. In fact, it will drastically reduce the overall time. See this example that I created.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oPPApp As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPPrsn As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oPPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant file
    FlName = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Documents\MyFile.PPTX"

    oPPApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant powerpoint file
    Set oPPPrsn = oPPApp.Presentations.Open(FlName)
    '~~> Change this to the relevant slide which has the shape
    Set oPPSlide = oPPPrsn.Slides(1)

    '~~> Change the background of the table in one go
    oPPSlide.Shapes(1).Table.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    formatTable oPPSlide.Shapes(1)

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub

Private Function formatTable(shp As PowerPoint.Shape)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, tabCol As Long

    With shp.Table
        tabCol = .Columns.Count
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For j = 1 To tabCol
                With .Cell(i, j).Shape
                    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
                        Select Case i
                            Case 1: .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                            Case 2, 6, 10, 14, 19: .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
                            Case 23: .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 153)
                            Case 27, 29, 31: .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(204, 255, 104)
'                            Case Else
'                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'                            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse
                        End Select
                        With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                            .Name = "Arial"
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(i = 1, vbWhite, vbBlack)
                            .Size = IIf(j <> 1 And i = 1, 7, 8)
                        End With
                        .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = IIf(j = 1, 1, 2)
                End With
                With .Cell(i, j)
                    .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Weight = 1
                    .Borders(ppBorderTop).Weight = 1
                    .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Weight = 1
                    .Borders(ppBorderRight).Weight = 1
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Siddharth,
I got rid of the else case, but it is still taking over 5 minutes to create the table.

Comment: I made it so powerpoint was not the active window, and it ran in about 45 seconds, so it looks like your solution worked. Thanks